# Add wp_enqueue_script() in functions.php

Tags: javascript, php, css, wordpress, wp-enqueue-scripts

I'm trying to add Maps JavaScript API in wordpress without plugins. I have seen that to do that I need to use the wp_enqueue_script() function.

However, I would like to know what is the correct way to add this function in the functions.php file?

Thank's

Comment: Checkout the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/). The first and most-upvoted comment shows an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function enqueue_custom_scripts() { 
  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-nname', 'https://www.script.com/script.js' ,array('jquery'),NULL,true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_scripts' );
```